# C# implementation- "Print all combinations of balanced parentheses"

Tags: java, c#, recursion

I implemented polygenelubricants's java code ([Valid Permutation of Parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172179/valid-permutation-of-parenthesis?noredirect=1&lq=1)) in C#.

My C# Code:

```
public static void CombiParentheses(int open, int close, StringBuilder str)
{
    if (open == 0 && close == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        str.Clear();
    }
    if (open > 0) //when you open a new parentheses, then you have to close one parentheses to balance it out.
    {                
        CombiParentheses(open - 1, close + 1, str.Append("{"));
    }
    if (close > 0)
    {                
        CombiParentheses(open , close - 1, str.Append("}"));
    }
}
```

However I'm getting the wrong result:

```
CombiParentheses(3, 0, tempString2);
{{{}}}
}{}}
}{}
}{{}}
}{}
```

What causes this difference between C# and Java implementation?

Comment: My gut feeling is that it is related to the usage of `StringBuilder` vs. `string` in the Java version. Note that `StringBuilder`'s manipulation functions such as `Append()` return the original `StringBuilder` object itself, not a new one.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Can you explain please? I don't see any other difference from the Java version. Maybe you're looking at the optimized version in the linked post?

Comment: The problem is that the java version uses strings. Strings are immutable. If you call the method recursive using strings you'll create a new string instance thats used in recursive call. You uses a StringBuilder and passes the same instance every time to every call. Lets take a look at your first rec. call: string passes `s + "{"` to the call. The same call but the second rec. call will pass the original `s` + `}`. Your StringBuilder instead will contain the opening brace added before.

Comment: To make it clear: First call: `open = close > 0`. `s = ""`, same like `str == ""`. At the first rec. call you pass `"{"` (because `s` is empty). Thats also the same like using StringBuilder. But the second rec. call will pass `"}"` in the string version because `s` is empty but it will pass `"{}"` in the StringBuilder version because you added a closing brace to the stringbuilder in the call before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in the Java->C# translation, but in the fact that you translated a string to a StringBuilder. When you call

```
str.Append("(");
```

You are appending "(" to the current string builder instance (`str`), and when you do

```
CombiParentheses(open - 1, close + 1, str.Append("("));
```

passing **that instance itself** on your method call, not a new instance.

An easy way to see the problem: suppose you're calling

```
CombiParentheses(2, 0, str);
```

When the second output string is written, the call stack will have been

```
CombiParentheses(2, 0, str):
    CombiParentheses(1, 1, str.Append("(")):
        CombiParentheses(0, 2, str.Append("(")):
            CombiParentheses(0, 1, str.Append(")")):
                CombiParentheses(0, 0, str.Append(")")); // StringBuilder was reset here!
        CombiParentheses(1, 0, str.Append(")")):
            CombiParentheses(0, 1, str.Append("(")):
                CombiParentheses(0, 0, str.Append(")"));
```

Since you're using a single string builder instance, and you cleared it right before the call stack went into

```
CombiParentheses(1, 0, str.Append(")"));
```

The next output will match the output of that call, **as if str had no characters on it yet**, not the output you're expecting (which would be as if str still had a `"("` on it).

If you used a string instead, when you do `(string + ")")`, the result is a **new** string, not the same object that you modified, so the problem doesn't arise, when you get back to a `CombiParentheses` call made earlier in the recursive execution you still have the original string that `CombiParentheses` call received.

You can use this do see it in runtime:

```
public static void CombiParentheses(int open, int close, StringBuilder str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("open: {0}; close: {1}; str: {2}", open, close, str.ToString());
    if (open == 0 && close == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        str.Clear();
    }

    if (open > 0)
    {
        CombiParentheses(open - 1, close + 1, str.Append("("));
    }

    if (close > 0)
    {
        CombiParentheses(open, close - 1, str.Append(")"));
    }
}

public static void CombiParenthesesFixed(int open, int close, string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("open: {0}; close: {1}; str: {2}", open, close, str);
    if (open == 0 && close == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

    if (open > 0)
    {
        CombiParentheses(open - 1, close + 1, str + "(");
    }

    if (close > 0)
    {
        CombiParentheses(open, close - 1, str + ")");
    }
}
```