# Algorithm for checking a given number is a sum of combinations in a given array

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm which will tell me if the input number is a combination of the given array.The numbers in the array can be used n number of times
Ex:- given array:-(1, 5, 7 and 10)
input:- 17( yes since 10x1 +7x1) 
        65( yes since 10x6 + 5x1).. Here 10 is used 6 times.
output:-2
        7

Comment: *65( yes since 6x10 + 5x1)*   I keep rubbing my aged eyes but can't see the `6` in the given array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Golf: Countdown Number Game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586814/code-golf-countdown-number-game)

Comment: Please add more details i.e. is it allowed to use a number more than once, is parenthesis allowed? Also there is no 6 in your array.

Comment: @xashru yes, The number can be used n number of times, 10 is multiplied 6 times

Comment: isn't it knapsack problem?

Comment: The answers might be interesting but problem seems a tad incompletely stated. What are all the rules, precisely ? Because so far indeed that's a knapsack problem. Seems to be solvable by linear programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use any number in the array any number of times, then there is an easy algorithm (but not the best one) and I am just going to describe the algorithm.

For a given number `M`, use the largest number in the array as many times as possible first. If `k` is the largest number, then find an `n` such that `k*n <= M` and `k*(n+1) > M`. Then use the second largest number in the array to fill in the gap between `k*n` and `M` and so on.

Example: if your array is `[1, 5, 7, 10]` and `M=138`, then use `10` (which is the largest number in the array) as many times as possible to get as closely to `M` without going over. In this case it's 13 times because `10*13 = 130 < M = 138` and `10*14 > 140 > 138 = M`. Then use the second largest number, 7, to fill in the missing piece which is 8 (`138-130`). Then, obviously try to use 5 (which doesn't work), and finally use 1. So you get 1+7+10*13 = 138.

The above algorithm is not guaranteed to work though. If our array was [5, 7, 10], then the algorithm is not going to find a solution, if one exists.